# Selecting a cell from a pandas dataframe that matches certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a credit card fraud detection project. I have 2 dataframes:

1. Credit card data with credit card number and credit card limit
2. Transaction data with credit card number and transaction amount

`credit_card_df` looks like this:

| credit_card | city | state | zipcode | credit_card_limit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1280981422329509 | Dallas | PA | 18612 | 6000 |
| 9737219864179988 | Houston | PA | 15342 | 16000 |

`transaction_df` looks like this:

| credit_card | date | amount | Long | Lat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1003715054175576 | 2015-09-11 | 43.78 | -80.174132 | 40.267370 |

I want to add a credit card limit column to `transaction_df`. To do this, I am running a code which is:

```
limit_ = []
for j in range(transaction_df.shape[0]):
    # for every row in transaction_df
    # Take the credit card number
    credit_card_num_j = transaction_df['credit_card'].values[j]
    #Take the credit limit
    limit_j = credit_card_df['credit_card_limit'].loc[credit_card_df ['credit_card'] == credit_card_num_j]
    limit_.append(limit_j)
```

The result is a list of rows that looks like this:

```
[915    20000
 Name: credit_card_limit, dtype: int64,
 915    20000
 Name: credit_card_limit, dtype: int64,
...]
```

I would like to select just the cell and not the entire row. Once I am able to do this, I will add a column to `transaction_df` with the following code:

```
transaction_df['limit'] = limit_
```

I would like to add that I have already tried concat and it did not not work.

**SOLVED**

```
# These are the credit card numbers for every transaction
trans_cred_values = transaction_df['credit_card'].values

# These are all the credit card numbers for which we have data
cc_values = credit_card_df['credit_card'].values

#These are all the corresponding credit card limits
cc_limit_values = credit_card_df['credit_card_limit'].values

limit_ = []
for j in range(transaction_df.shape[0]):
    # for every row in transaction_df
    # Take the credit card number
    credit_card_num_j = trans_cred_values[j]
    
    #Take the credit limit
    for k in range(credit_card_df.shape[0]):
        if credit_card_num_j == cc_values[k]:
            limit_jk = cc_limit_values[k]
            limit_.append(limit_jk)
```

Comment: `transaction_df['limit'] = credit_card_df.set_index('credit_card')['credit_card_limit']`

Comment: @mozway That did not work. I tried something else. I will update the question to include the solution